# Macros inaccessible from an embedded workbook of a PowerPoint chart

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

I have an embedded excel open and I am trying to run a macro which is available in an open .xlsm file. For some reason the macro dialog box doesn't list the available macros. Any pointers is much much appreciated. Please see the below pic for clarity.

Kindly don't flag the question as this is a general query, so no coding involved.

[image]

Comment: Embedded Excel files use OLE. OLE doesn't include the capability of accessing macros in embedded objects. Instead, _link_ the Excel file. Then the macros will still be able to run. You can even call them from PowerPoint, if required.

Comment: Thanks much John. But unfortunately this is really a bummer..... :(